# Parsing XML using SimpleXML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i have a xml structure of the following form to be parsed using PHP simplexml.

```
<books>

<book>
<title>XYZ</title>
<author> someone </author>
<images>
<image type="poster" url="<url>" size="cover" id="12345"/>
<image type="poster" url="<url>" size="thumb" id="12345"/>
</images>
</book>

<book>
<title>PQR</title>
<author> someoneelse </author>
<images>
<image type="poster" url="<url>" size="cover" id="67890"/>
<image type="poster" url="<url>" size="thumb" id="67890"/>
</images>
</book>

</books>
```

Suppose i want to print the title of the first book. I am able to do that using

```
$books = $xml->books; 
$book = $books->book[0]; //Get the first book
print $book->title; //This works
```

But,when i try to print all the image urls for this book it does not work. The code im using is:

```
$books = $xml->books; 
$book = $books->book[0]; //Get the first book
$images=$book->images;

foreach($images as $image) //This does not work
{
   print $image->url;
}
```

Any way to fix this problem ?

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
foreach ($xml->book[0]->images->image as $image) {
  echo $image['url'] . "\n";
}
```

See [SimpleXML Basic usage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

Answer (score 2):

The url is an attribute, not a child element. Try this:

```
print $image->attributes()->url;
```

[Documentation here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)

Comment: Thanks for the reply nick. But i seem to be having a strange problem here. print $images->image[0]->attributes()->url prints the url of the first image correctly,but again the below loop for printing the urls of all the images does not work...what could be wrong here ? foreach($images as $image) { print $image->attributes()->url; }

Comment: You also need to do foreach ($images->image as $image)